# Changes in @media do not appear

Tags: html, jquery, css

I tried to create a responsive menu for a smaller screen, but the icon fa fa-bar would not appear, even though I set display: block inside media query. I wonder what the priority in css is. I followed a tutorial on reponsive menu, yet my code in media does not reflect on the smaller screen.

```
nav {
  display: flex;
  padding: 2% 6%;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
.nav img {
  width: 150px;
}
.nav-links {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: right;
}
.nav-links ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: relative;
}
.nav-links ul li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 500;
}
.nav-links ul li::after {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
.nav-links ul li:hover::after {
  width: 100%;
}
@media (max-width: 700px) {
.nav-links ul li {
    display: block;
  }

  .nav-links {
    position: absolute;
    background: #012a5d;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 200px;
    top: 0;
    right: -200px;
    text-align: left;
    z-index: 2;
    transition: 1s;
  }

  nav.fa {
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 10px;
    font-size: 22px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .nav-links ul {
    padding: 30px;
  }
}
```

```
<nav>
                <div class="logo">
                    <a href="index.html"><img src="images/Logos/University of Toronto Logos/U of T Signature_Reverse RGB (1).png"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="nav-links" id="navLinks">
                    <i class="fa fa-times" onclick="hideMenu()"></i>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                        ...
                        <li><a href="contact.html" class="button-header">
                            <div class="button-font">
                                Contact Us
                            </div>
                        </a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <i class="fa fa-bars" onclick="showMenu()"></i>
            </nav>
<script>
            var navLinks = document.getElementById("navLinks");
            function showMenu()
                {navlinks.style.right ="0";}
            function hideMenu() 
                { navlinks.style.right = "-200";}
        </script>
```

[how the menu looks like on a big screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/loX3f.jpg)

Comment: To override element style in CSS, use `!important`

Comment: `nav.fa` doesn't exist in your html block - try `nav > i.fa-bars`

Comment: Do not use `!important` - this is overkill. This is a typo as Andrew pointed out.

Comment: @CanO'Spam for future reference, while `!important` works it should be avoided as much as possible. Instead, use [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) to override a style.